# Clicking away from popup window

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, click, protractor, chrome-web-driver

In the app there is a plot which when clicked open a floating popup window.

There are multiple ways of closing the pop up **e.g.** clicking close button on pop up window or clicking outside that window.

I just want to know how I can simulate clicking outside popup window with protractor?

Comment: I have not tried anything yet for this, but just found this a while ago
'var canvas = element(by.id("canvas"));

var clickCanvas = function (toRight, toBottom) { 
    browser.actions()
      .mouseMove(canvas, {x: toRight, y: toBottom})
      .click()
      .perform();
};'
So I will continue with trying that..

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways of doing it however one of the easiest would be to move mouse to a particular location and click. It can be done simply by -

```
browser.actions().
    mouseMove({x: 50, y: 0}).
    doubleClick().
    perform();
```

Also give the x and y co-ordinates as per your page and requirements.
This will only work if you have switched to pop-up window!

Comment: Just wondering, Is it possible to use it with single click instead of double. I tried click() and singleclick() but it does not work.

Comment: Hey, No it wont work with click() because single click is not a browser action !!